# Webpack path resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a SFCC project with multiple sites in one repository. Here is a brief overview of the structure of the codebase:

- core

  - cartridge
  - js

    - something

      - dialog.js
  - modal.js
  - app.js
  - shirt.js
- site_1

  - cartridge
  - js

    - page

      - file1.js
  - app1.js
- site_2

  - cartridge
  - js

    - page

      - file2.js
  - app2.js
- site_3

  - cartridge
  - js

    - page

      - file3.js
  - app3.js
- build

  - site1.js
  - site2.js
  - site3.js

My webpack entry points are the site1, site2, and site3 js files. In each of those files, I am importing the respective app.js file. Each of these app.js files has their own files that they require for that particular site. When I run webpack I get the Module not found error.

In the app.js files, I am requiring outside dependencies like so:

require('./dialog.js')

The error for this example would be something like this:

ERROR in ../[site]/cartridge/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dialog' in '/path/to/repository/[site]/cartridge/js'

Any idea how I can concatenate the correct path to to these files?

Answer (score 0):

Create an [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) to core directory. Then require/import using `[alias]/js/something/dialog.js`